# How to PUT just GETted entity with OneToMany relation back

Tags: spring-data-rest

For example I have those entities (slightly modified entities from [restbucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks) example):

```
class Order {
  // ID, getters etc
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  Set<Item> items;
}

class Item {
  // ID, getters etc
  @ManyToOne
  Order order;
}
```

And `Repository` for **each**.

Now if I `GET /orders/1` then have a JSON with simple fields of `order` and link to the `items` of that order in `_links` attribute.

If I then modify some fields and just `PUT` that JSON back to `/orders/1` then all fields modified correctly but in addition `Set<Item> items` is cleared. Actually they deleted as `orphanRemoval = true`. In hibernate logs I see:

```
Hibernate: select order0_.id as id1_3_0_, order0_.location as location2_3_0_, order0_.ordered_date as ordered_3_3_0_, order0_.status as status4_3_0_ from rborder order0_ where order0_.id=?
Hibernate: select items0_.order_id as order_id8_3_0_, items0_.id as id1_1_0_, items0_.id as id1_1_1_, items0_.milk as milk2_1_1_, items0_.name as name3_1_1_, items0_.order_id as order_id8_1_1_, items0_.currency as currency4_1_1_, items0_.value as value5_1_1_, items0_.quantity as quantity6_1_1_, items0_.size as size7_1_1_ from item items0_ where items0_.order_id=?
Hibernate: update rborder set location=?, ordered_date=?, status=? where id=?
Hibernate: delete from item where id=
```

But what if I need preserve that items? I must use `PATCH`? What if I want not to track from client which fields changes.

For example:

1. GET order from JS and assign it to variable
2. Do some changes to fields. Not track **which** fields changed.
3. PUT changed order back to the server.

Now the order has no items.

Comment: There's no need to track which fields have changed when you use PATCH.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is the intended purpose of PATCH.

> Several applications extending the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)
> require a feature to do partial resource modification.  The existing
> HTTP PUT method only allows a complete replacement of a document. This
> proposal adds a new HTTP method, PATCH, to modify an existing HTTP
> resource.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789

Comment: The question is more about how to PUT with **spring-data-rest**. I know what is PATCH but with spring-data-rest we can't PUT at all? Because we always GET JSON without relations in embedded entity.

Comment: @djxak, what version of spring-data-rest are you using? I can do both a PUT and a PATCH to parent/1 without losing the parent's children.

Comment: I tried spring-data-rest 2.2.0.RC1. Actually I tried to play with [spring-restbucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks) project but change unidirectional mapping to bidirectional and expose `ItemRepository` for not inlining items in order. Now if I `GET /orders/1` and then PUT just what I get to the same URI, then items of that order all deleted.